# One or two tables for forum?

Tags: mysql, database, forum

Im building a forum and I'm wondering whether I should have one table where I store all main posts and then all the answers in another table.

I've always stored everything in one table, making it east to count and let users comment every post (comments in another table).

What should I do? Pros and cons? Tried to google but didn't find anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Reading about database normalization would help you a lot, not only for this specific issue, but for future problems also.

Comment: @FarukSahin I understand that the "right" way is two use to seperate tables. But please see my comment on Pleuns answer.

Comment: You need to learn about Relational Database and Normalization.

Comment: You could take a look at one of the many forums available as open source and see what they do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually follow the rule `every type of dataset gets a own table`. This way you can cleanly define relationships

You have types like

- userTypes (e.g. guest,user,mod,admin)
- users (has one userType_id)
- posts (has one user_id)
- answers (has one post_id)
- comments (has one post_id, has one answer_id)

Since comments can be added for both, a post and an answer, you could add two bridge tables to define this relationship.

- comment_to_answer (has one comment_id, has one answer_id)
- comment_to_question (has one comment_id, has one question_id)

In case you save both, posts and answers into one table, posts table would need to reference themselves to define the posts - answers one-to-many relationship, which would make querying more complicated.

If you want to be able to cascade, post can have an answer, answer can have an answer and so on, you probably go better with one posts table and a parent_id pointing at the id of posts

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it also makes it more complicated when inserting comments, since it goes to different tables depending on if the comment is for a post or an answer, right? I understand that the "right" way is two seperate tables, but to me it just seems to be more work, mainly because of the comments.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to seperate when writing the comment-to-post / comment-to-answer relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly subjective, given that it depends on your needs and intentions. Let me explain...

Forums, such as they are, usually take one of two forms. They are sometimes in the form of a main post, with subsequent comments. The main post, therefore logically would live in one table, and the comments in another. Facebook and Stack Exchange sites are examples of this.

In other cases, the content may take the form of a list of comments. More traditional forums take this form. In the case where hierarchy is called for, rather than pure date ordering, the single table approach makes more sense.

In both cases, hierarchy can be dealt with by creating a `parent` and `child` column.

My personal preference would be to go with one table, unless the main post contains an order of additional data that isn't needed for comments. That's just an efficiency thing, but you definitely don't want thousands or millions of rows with `NULL`s that take up space to no avail. To distinguish a post from a comment you can employ any number of logical schemes such as distinct ID's or flag columns.

Ultimately, an architectural situation like this depends on the project in question. There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches. Using multiple tables offers a little more in the way of 'future proofing' your project in the case where complexity is added at a later date.

Answer (score -1):

Well - since one post can have multiple answers I would go for a separate table.

Pro:

- Less redundant information
- Answer can be updated/deleted independent from the post
- Easier counting of questions / answers

Con

- Non (well, perhaps that you need to join the tables for certain queries, but hey that does not really count)

Same reason why you have comments already in another table...

Comment: But then I would have to store whether the comment belongs to a main post or an answer in the comments table, since the same post id can/will occur in the main posts table and in the answers table, right? That does not seem very good.

Comment: You probably need to do that anyway - otherwise you loose information and you cannot present (display) the comment to a post or to an answer (eg. like stackoverflow does). If you do not need that information you can always relate it to the main question and no problem in your datamodel

Comment: No, if main posts and answers were in the same table the comment table would only need these fields: comment_id | ref_post_id (references to forum table) | content | ref_user_id
With two tables it would also need a field to tell whether the comment is for a main post or an answer.

Comment: So there you have a con :)

Comment: Not really - since you need exactly the same field in your main table, otherwise you do not know it is a question or answer.