# Get last forum post

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a forum, where I have all main thread posts in one database table, and all answers in another. So far, it's been a hell to have two tables.

```
forum_threads
thread_id | title | post

forum_answers
answer_id | ref_thread_id (foreign key) | post
```

How do I select the latest post, including the threads title? The thread might not have any answer, in which case all data should come from forum_thread. But if it has an answer data should be selected from forum_answers and also the title which is found in forum_threads.

Hope you understand!

This would be way easier if I had it all in one table, answers and main posts. Although I was told this was the best way, not so sure..... I'm considering switching back to only one table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why not to have single table for this?

Comment: Also i see not a single date field in either table

Comment: Do you want to get main post and last forum post as one row? Specify your DB please.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I guess OP supposed there can't be a foreign key from one table to itself. To OP: add a foreign key `thread_id` to itself, and allow it to be null. If it's null it means it is a post, and if it's not it is an answer to the post id=`thread_id`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Using a single table is the way I've built all my forums so far. But then I asked on SO whether I should use one or two tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109838/one-or-two-tables-for-forum About all of the answer told me to use separate tables.

Comment: Can you have multiple answers per thread?? If so, you want to use 2 tables. If it will always be 1:1, then use 1 table and make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want, but you should really store dates in those tables.

```
SELECT
    ft.thread_id,
    ft.title,
    COALESCE(fa.post,ft.post) AS post
FROM
    forum_threads ft
LEFT JOIN
    forum_answers fa
    ON  (ft.thread_id = fa.ref_thread_id)
ORDER BY
    ft.thread_id
LIMIT 1;
```

It will give you the `post` value from `forum_answers` unless there isn't one for that thread, then it will just give you the `post` value from `forum_threads`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT fa.post, ft.title
FROM forum_threads ft INNER JOIN forum_answers fa ON
     ft.thread_id = fa.ref_thread_id
ORDER BY fa.answer_id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yea, but this eliminates the non-answered threads, which I don't think the OP wants.